# 2002 Honda Accord special edition

Tags: honda, accord, overheating, radiator

Replaced radiator just yesterday. Engine temp gage went past the HOT. The Honda engine  isn’t smoking or leaking. Please advise?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What *exactly* is your question or your concern here?

Comment: Have you bled it properly to get any air out of the cooling system?

Comment: Yes sir everything is in good running order thank you for you input.